# How to display the created flow on corda

Tags: corda

when I create a flow, they do not appear in the flow list. Do I need to create them in the cordapp module? Project builds normally.

Project schema[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxves.png)

Comment: Are you able to share the source code? I can't see anything wrong based on those pictures.

Comment: Found that I in deployNodes did not write a block of cordapps. Tell me if the flow is in the same module as the server, how to register the path inside the cordapps. Build.gradle -> task DeployNodes -> node -> cordapps = ["what is there to write"]

Comment: I'm not convinced this is the issue. Does the CorDapp appear in the node's `cordapps` folder?

Answer (score 0):

So without the source code, there's no way for us to really know why it doesn't appear in the list.

It's worth mentioning there are some obscure bugs as well, I suspect that what you're running into here is that your code isn't overriding the progressTracker.

Note the docs here:

> Flows cannot be run unless they override the progress tracker

So just try to keep that in mind that it could be causing your issue.

Here's a progressTracker example from the yo cordapp on the corda github.

```
public class YoFlow extends FlowLogic<SignedTransaction> {
    private static final ProgressTracker.Step CREATING = new ProgressTracker.Step("Creating a new Yo!");
    private static final ProgressTracker.Step SIGNING = new ProgressTracker.Step("Signing the Yo!");
    private static final ProgressTracker.Step VERIFYING = new ProgressTracker.Step("Verfiying the Yo!");
    private static final ProgressTracker.Step FINALISING = new ProgressTracker.Step("Sending the Yo!") {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public ProgressTracker childProgressTracker() {
            return FinalityFlow.tracker();
        }
    };

    ProgressTracker progressTracker = new ProgressTracker(
            CREATING,
            SIGNING,
            VERIFYING,
            FINALISING
    );

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ProgressTracker getProgressTracker() {
        return progressTracker;
    }

    private final Party target;

    public YoFlow(Party target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Suspendable
    @Override
    public SignedTransaction call() throws FlowException {
        progressTracker.setCurrentStep(CREATING);
```

Source: Docs limitations page: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/shell.html#limitations